# Use of low rank approximation of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

I am trying to figure out why do we need a [low rank approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation) of a matrix. Why is it used and where? Any insights?

Comment: For example, if your matrix represents a graphic image, you could use a low rank approximation of it as a form of lossy compression.

Answer (score 0):

Please, read http://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.3599.pdf, page 3. This might be helpful.

I have also reformulated your question a bit here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906417/applications-of-low-rank-matrix-approximation